# What is PostGIS doing with ST_DistanceSphere?

Tags: mysql, spatial

PostGIS `ST_Distance_Sphere` and `ST_DistanceSphere` return the same thing in PostGIS 2.2.

[`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_DistanceSphere.html) says

> Uses a spherical earth and radius derived from the spheroid defined by the SRID.

[`ST_Distance_Sphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) says,

> Uses a spherical earth and radius of [6370986 meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262468/6052)

I'm looking into [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191276/2639), specifically

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere( ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(0,1) );
 st_distancesphere 
-------------------
   111195.07973463
(1 row)
```

Currently that returns `111195.07973463`, it seems it should return

```
SELECT ((6370986 * 1 * pi()) / 180) AS distance_on_sphere
 distance_on_sphere 
--------------------
   111194.682298463
(1 row)
```

That's a difference of `0.397436166531406`, almost half a meter. [Wolfram Apha shows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(6370986+*+1+*+pi)+%2F+180)

```
111194.6822984634581396675695437019275676654860169289329663
```

Which puts Wolfram at a more precise version of my napkin math and [on par with MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191276/2639) `((6370986 * 1 * pi()) / 180)` and validates that `ST_DistanceSphere` is borked.

What's going on here?

```
POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. Though it calculates the distance on a sphere, PostGIS doesn't calculate with the major-axis radius in WGS84 as presumed in the question. The sphere is created with a radius that is the [mean radius of the WGS84 ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radius). This is by design.
2. Neither does MySQL, however [the radius in MySQL was lifted from a lazy-copy-job from PostGIS that converted a radius in miles to meters from an obscure constant from a random 20-year old PostgreSQL module.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/262457/6052) Far from by design, this is presumed to be a bug.